# Pandas:Find newly added data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-processing

I have two dumps of data , the old dump and the new dump.

Old dump goes like:-
[image]

New Dump is the changed data or the newly added data.
My goal is to find the newly added data.

Sample new dump goes like:-

[image]

For the actual implementation i am querying old dump from the database , and new dump is the weekly files received for any new adds or updates

I am using the below code to find the newly adds , but something is not right as when i go to find the duplicate id's it gives  blank dataframe even though the duplicates are present.
Below id my code:-

```
cols_to_show=["id","fname","lname","title","yearjoined"]
    prev_batch=pd.read_csv("sample1.csv",encoding='cp1252',sep='\t',error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True) #olddump
    current_batch=pd.read_csv("sample2",encoding='cp1252',sep='\t',error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True) #newdump
    
    prev_batch['version']='v0.0'
    current_batch['version']='v1.0'
    full_set = pd.concat([prev_batch,current_batch],ignore_index=True)
    changes = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_to_show, keep='last')
    dupe=changes[changes.duplicated('id',keep=False)] #gives empty dataframe

    change_new = dupe_lawyers[(dupe["version"] == 'v1.0')]

    change_old = dupe_lawyers[(dupe["version"] == 'v0.0')]
    changes['duplicate']=changes["id"].isin(dupe["id"])
    new_added = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_to_show, keep='first')
    
    new_added['duplicate']=new_added["id"].isin(dupe["id"])
    
    
    added_new = new_added[(new_lawyers["duplicate"] == False)&(new_added["version"] == "v1.0")]
```

I am not able to understand why dupe is giving me empty dataframe

Comment: you are dropping duplicates and keeping only the last with this statement `changes = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_to_show, keep='last')`. Therefore, `change` will have no duplicates. Later you are checking for duplicates and picking only duplicates to create `dupe`. Obviously, it will be empty as you eliminated all duplicates when you created `changes`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you are looking for an answer only to the code that you have provided, but another approach could be to use the pandas `compare` API to get the difference between the dataframes. I am showing an example below taken from their [website](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"],
        "col2": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, np.nan, 5.0],
        "col3": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
    },
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
)

df2 = df.copy()
df2.loc[0, 'col1'] = 'c'
df2.loc[2, 'col3'] = 4.0
df2

diff_df = df.compare(df2)
```

After this you can get the difference using the `xs` [api](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and get the difference of the dataframe.

```
diff_df.xs('other', level=1, axis=1)
```

For this case will be the following:

[image]